# Is using start and end index method the only way to implement a binary search?

Tags: python, binary-search

Below is my code, when I use `test_function` it returns fail.  It should return pass.
What is wrong with making the stop criteria of loop to be length of array == 1 and using length of array as reference for defining middle index.
All tutorials explain this using start and end index method, is that the only way?

```
def binary_search(array, target):
    current_index=(len(array)-1)//2
    while len(array)>1:
        if array[current_index]!=target:
            if target>array[current_index]:
                array = array[((len(array)-1)//2)+1:]
                current_index=((len(array)-1)//2)
            else: 
                array = array[:((len(array)-1)//2)-1]
                current_index=(len(array)-1)//2
        else: return current_index
    return -1

def test_function(test_case):
    answer = binary_search(test_case[0], test_case[1])
    if answer == test_case[2]:
        print("Pass!")
    else:
        print("Fail!")

array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
target = 6
index = 6
test_case = [array, target, index]
test_function(test_case)
```

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: You are returning `current_index`, which is an index into *the current subdivision of the original array*.  If that subdivision doesn't happen to be at the very start, then this value does not match the index in the original array.  Passing start/end indexes is the usual solution, and is much more efficient since you're not creating all these subdivided lists.

Comment: Slicing the array on each iteration can be made to work, but it's slow as it performs a copy. It will probably make your binary search slower than a sequential search. That's why normally indexes are used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of errors. My general advice: include a lot of output to understand how your code actually works and play around with parameters. A test function is a good start, you should call it with multiple test cases.

Your list slicing has wrong indices when selecting the lower part.

When your list is down to a single element and that is a match, you will return -1.
And then there is a conceptual error: you don't keep track of the index in the original list, e.g. when you fix the other errors, it will return 0 instead of 6. You can fix that by keeping track of the index offset